# Create and store a dataset from BigQuery database using SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm analyzing the [data of New York City taxi trips of yellow cars in 2018](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/bigquery-public-data:new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2018). (You need a Google BigQuery account to access this data set.)

I need to analyze only the data for December.  Thus, to reduce the querying time, I would like to

1. create a subset of the data for December
2. save it somewhere
3. refer to it later for more analyses

How do I do this in BigQuery?  To get started, I can run

```
#standardSQL
select * 
from [bigquery-public-data:new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2018] 
WHERE month(dropoff_datetime) = 12
```

What is the next step?

Comment: you have already three bullets in your question - just follow them. any issue there? I think you should ask more specific question(s)

Comment: I don't know how to do Steps 2-3. Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CREATE` command to do this

This is a `CREATE` SQL example:

```
CREATE TABLE `myProject.myDataset.myDestinationTable` AS
select * 
from `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2018`
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dropoff_datetime) = 12
```

Note: I also changed your SQL to match standard SQL syntax

OR use BQ [webUI](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery) to save your results to a destination table (Very simple)

[image]